# How to pass Glue annotations for multiple inputs in AWS for multiple input source

Tags: amazon-web-services, annotations, cloud, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

Glue diagram is generated as per the annotations passed to it and edges are created as per @input frame value passed, I want to generate diagram where it should take multiple inputs as there should be multiple edges coming to vertex for each source but in all the example it's given for single input source only , I tried comma separated value but in that diagram it is not getting generated at all. If anyone can share a link to blog or video where annotation is explained in more detail that will also be very helpful,

```
## @type: DataSink
## @args: [connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://example-data-destination/taxi-data"}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2"]
## @return: datasink2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer , just for future reference if someone else get's stuck in this situation ## @inputs: [frame1 = applymapping1,frame2 = applymapping2,frame3 = applymapping3,frame4 = applymapping4 ]